# How to do a simple dataGridView search / filter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, datatable

Yeah, I have an event-driven Windows Form project made in Visual Studio C#.  It's a telephone diary that I made from scratch. It is actually working fine but I just want to add another feature for the user.

The user enters the contacts, wants to add to the datagridview with their details. And they can **add** them, can **edit** them as needed while the program is running, can **add (import)** more people from an excel file, and then can **export** it to a new excel file.  So nothing is saved to the program, everything they want to do has to happen during runtime of the program and be exported to new excel file as needed.

So everything works fine but **I want to let the user *search* the current datagrid (dataGridView1) in the program (in-app) and I can't figure out how.**

I have it where the user can sort the columns ascending / descending (that is a built in feature of the data grid), but I would like to have the specific text search.  I don't want to make a MySqlConnection and all of that, I just want to be able to, say, go into the search button and program it (on click) to only search where searchTextBox is equal to a value in any cell of my dataGridView1, and display only those results.

Not sure why it's so difficult to find, is it possible?  I would think it would be simple, but I haven't been able to find out how to do it.  Below is a picture of my application as of now.  Also if you happen to have any ideas as to how to make it better for the user that would be nice. (:

[image: Address book / telephone diary]

Comment: Maybe you can save the data to a DataTable

Comment: What are you having a problem with, *specifically?*  "I can't get it to work" is not a problem statement.  If you're trying to "program by Google," learning slowly and carefully how to do the things you need to do to make it work is a better (and more productive) approach.  As @gnat so eloquently points out, you're probably posting your question in the wrong place, but Stack Overflow is going to want to see your code.  Without code, there's nothing to fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just try this , Have a look,

```
    private void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string searchValue = searchtextBox.Text;
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    try
    {
        bool valueResult = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Value != null && row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    int rowIndex = row.Index;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                    valueResult = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (!valueResult)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find " + searchtextBox.Text, "Not Found");
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are people down-voting this?  I followed your code and it is doing exactly what I wanted.  But you would want to add ToUpper() - so it looks like  row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().ToUpper() and string searchValue = searchTextBox.Text.ToUpper().   Just to make it not case sensitive.  Thanks again I thought it was something along those lines but I couldn't figure it out.