# How to display data after querying it via Windows Form App?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, mariadb

I've got one simple Windows Forms App with a data grid view connected to my MariaDB. I've added "Add entries" and "Delete entries" buttons but I'm having trouble adding a "Search" button. I also have six text boxes which represent a value of one column in my database (6 columns total) and I use them to add entries into the grid/database. I want to use those same text boxes for a search function (when I press "Search" to display all entries with that column value).

This is what I've came up with but it didn't work in the end. I know the issue is in the last few lines, I don't know how to display the new data table in my data grid view. Thanks in advance.

```
private void btnPretraga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MariaDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection konekcija = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        konekcija.Open();
        string upit = "SELECT * FROM drvnisortiment WHERE (vrstaDrveta = @VrstaDrveta OR duzinaM = @DuzinaM OR precnikCM = @PrecnikCM OR klasa=@Klasa OR redniBrDoznake=@RedniBrDoznake OR vrstaSlUzitka=@VrstaSlUzitka)";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(upit, konekcija))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(upit, connString);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrstaDrveta", vrstaDrvetatextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DuzinaM", duzinaMtextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecnikCM", precnikCMtextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Klasa", klasatextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RedniBrDoznake", redniBrDoznaketextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrstaSlUzitka", vrstaSlUzitkatextBox.Text);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SDA.Fill(ds, "drvnisortiment");
            drvniSortimentGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a simple dataGridView search / filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208102/how-to-do-a-simple-datagridview-search-filter)

Comment: @Mikael no, this only works on a data grid that's not connected to an actual database.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs when the form that contains the DataGridView LOADS
consider using a SQLite.SQLiteDataReader

```
   Private Sub ViewSearches()

    Dim intID As Integer
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strAmt As Decimal
    Dim strYear As Integer
    Dim strSM As Integer

    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim maxRowCount As Integer
    Dim emptyStr As String = "  "


    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")

        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)

            If gvSearchType = "All" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData"
                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$intID", intID)
                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$strDate", strDate)
                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$strAmt", strAmt)
                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", strYear)
                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvSM", strSM)

            ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoRangeYr" Then
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData"
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txAmount >= '1.00' OR  txAmount <= '2.00'"
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth >= $gvFromMonth AND txSearchMonth <= $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth BETWEEN $gvFromMonth AND $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvToMonth", gvToMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            End If


            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvTX.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above is when DB is bound to dgvTX
                '============================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("TID")))
                    strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString
                    strAmt = CDec(rdr("txAmount"))
                    strYear = CInt(rdr("txYear").ToString)
                    strSM = CInt(rdr("txSearchMonth").ToString) 'was txSearchMonth

                    'dgvTX.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"

                    dgvTX.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C" 'Adds the $ sign and commas
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(intID, strDate, strAmt, strYear, strSM, emptyStr)
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1

                End While
                If rowCount <= 25 Then
                    maxRowCount = 25 - rowCount
                    For iA = 1 To maxRowCount
                        dgvTX.Rows.Add(" ")
                    Next
                End If

                'dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"

                dgvTX.Sort(dgvTX.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Ascending)

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Class